# Condition for an invertible operator on a Hilbert $C^*$-module

Tags: hilbert-spaces, c-star-algebras, hilbert-modules

If $H_1$ and $H_2$ are Hilbert spaces and $T:H_1\rightarrow H_2$ a bounded linear operator, then one can show that $T$ is invertible if and only if there exists a constant $\alpha > 0$ such that $T^*T\geq\alpha I_{H_1}$ and $TT^*\geq\alpha I_{H_2}$.

My query is: if $H_1$ and $H_2$ are now Hilbert $C^*$-modules over some (not necessarily unital) $C^*$-algebra $A$, and $T$ is an adjointable operator $H_1\rightarrow H_2$, is it true that

1) $T^*T$ and $TT^*$ being positive elements in $\text{End}(H_1)$ and $\text{End}(H_2)$ respectively is equivalent to $T$ being invertible?

2) If the answer to 1) is no, is there another analogue of the Hilbert space result that is true for Hilbert modules?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since the adjointable operators on $H_1$ (or $H_2$) form a C$^*$-algebra, one can reason the same as in the Hilbert space case.

Namely, if $T^*T\geq\alpha I_{H_1}$, then $T^*T$ is invertible, so there exists $X\in \text{End}(H_1)$ with $XT^*T=I_{H_1}$. Similarly, if $TT^*\geq\alpha I_{H_2}$ then there exists $Y$ with $TT^*Y=I_{H_2}$. So $T$ is invertible.

Conversely, if $T$ is invertible, let $Z$ be its inverse. Then $$T^*TZZ^*=T^*Z^*=(ZT)^*=I_{H_1}^*=I_{H_1}.$$ Similarly, $ZZ^*T^*T=I_{H_1}$. As $T^*T$ is positive and invertible in the C$^*$-algebra $\text{End}(H_1)$, there exists $\beta>0$ with $T^*T\geq\beta I_{H_1}$. Repeating the argument now for $T^*$, there exists $\gamma>0$ with $TT^*\geq\gamma I_{H_2}$. Now take $\alpha=\min\{\beta,\gamma\}$.